# Access multiplie attributes in a single SQLAlchemy validator

Tags: python, validation, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a simple Flask REST API (with SQLAlch as my db framewrok of choice) as a backend for an even simpler web application. I am currently trying to implement data validation.

```py
class Flight(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  departure = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
  arrival = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
  seats = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

  @validates('departure', 'arrival')
  def validate_dates(self, key, date):
    if not isinstance(date, datetime.datetime):
      raise TypeError(f"Departure or Arrival is type {type(date)}. Should be datetime.datetime.")

    # arrival - departure eval
```

The way Alch validations run, `validate_dates` runs twice, once for every attribute provided to the decorator, each time passing it to the "date" variable. I need to compare `departure` and `arrival` datetime.datetime objects though. At the time where this validator runs, self.arrival and self.departure are not yet defined.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright - figured it out.

```py
class Flight(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  departure = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
  arrival = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
  seats = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

  @validates('departure')
  def validate_dates(self, key, date):
    if not isinstance(date, datetime.datetime):
      raise TypeError(f"Departure is type {type(date)}. Should be datetime.datetime.")

    return date

  @validates('arrival')
  def validate_arrival(self, key, date):
    if not isinstance(date, datetime.datetime):
      raise TypeError(f"Arrival is type {type(date)}. Should be datetime.datetime.")

    time_diff = date - self.departure
    if time_diff <= datetime.timedelta(0):
      raise ValueError(f"Arrival time happens before departure time.")

    return date
```

If we validate them separately, `self.departure` is defined by the time `validate_arrival()` runs. Can reference that to compare the two and fail the arrival check.